# How to use oauth with 1st party client-side js app?

Tags: api, authentication, oauth, jwt

The model for our product is like this:

**Api backend (headless)**

I already have oauth set up and ready to use with a **[resource owner credentials grant](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.3)**. Anyone who wants to use our api can do so using either an API key or their username/password. Of course they also need their client ID and secret.

**SPA frontend that accesses the Api**

I have built an SPA that will uses the api to provide a portal GUI for our clients. Given that this client-side app is owned and administrated by us (so it's a trusted app) **how can I safely authenticate users using only username/password with oauth?**

---

Originally it was using a JWT auth system that only required username/pass but now that we've implemented oauth I'd like to consolidate. It's unreasonable to make every user need to also have their client id and secret on hand to login, but I want users to have full access to the api from the GUI.

I've looking at using CSRF tokens but how would that work with my app when nothing is generated server-side?

I'm not sure how to proceed.

EDIT: very similar [to the problem here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6190381/how-to-keep-the-client-credentials-confidential-while-using-oauth2s-resource-o).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have decided to use [the solution described here](http://alexbilbie.com/2014/11/oauth-and-javascript/).

[And here is a snippet of my implementation](https://gist.github.com/FoxxMD/207fc6f6545d07741537)

The TL;DR version is

1. Create a proxy between the app and the api
2. Store the client ID and secret in the proxy
3. App logs in using **password grant type** -- proxy intercepts login request and inserts client id and secret
4. On login response proxy returns access token **as an encrypted cookie**
5. Client stores cookie and sends with api requests (to proxy)
6. Proxy decrypts cookie and inserts access token into Authorization header before forwarding to api endpoint

For me this has several advantages over implementing something custom on the api itself:

- No need for custom grant on oauth server
- ID/secret is hidden from app securely and can still use password grant
- oauth server can identify client (no need for separate client ids for each user)

Comment: Do you have some sample code of the proxy? I would be much appreciated.

Comment: It's a bit messy but [here's what I'm using now](https://gist.github.com/FoxxMD/207fc6f6545d07741537)

Comment: Is there any downside of using this?

Answer (score 1):

You should not use the resource owner credential grant from a JavaScript application. The fact that you own and administer the application does not make it a trusted application.

A trusted client is an application that can keep a secret. SPAs or any JavaScript app cannot keep a secret.

You should use the [implicit grant](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.2) for non-trusted clients.

Comment: An implicit grant does not give enough authority to the user though. The api, along with the gui, is for administration and almost entirely non-public.

Comment: Not sure what you mean with 'does not give enough authority to the user'. You'll need to implement RBAC at the API level.